# Cannot open documents of Sharepoint in browser

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint 2019 on a Windows Server 2016 and cannot open office documents on the browser, it just download them.

I read that I have to install an Office web apps but I searched and did not found information about it.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be better posted at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

It's now called the Office Online Server. You install it on its own server and then link it to your SharePoint 2019 server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server

Depending on your Microsoft subscriptions, it's downloadable from the Volume Licensing Service Center (VLSC) or your MSDN downloads.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike

Comment: Hi! I checked it. You can’t download it from VLSC and in specs of windows server 2016, you have to install OFFICE ONLINE SERVER 2017 or later but I don’t know where can I get it

Comment: I don't think there is a "2017" version. I've seen it described as an "evergreen" product. The current download in my MSDN subscription is labeled as "Office Online Server (Last Updated November 2017)".

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Blog/Office-Online-Server-November-2017-Release/ba-p/125612

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server
   
"For customers whose licenses qualfiy for OOS, but cannot obtain it through the VLSC, the following actions are possible:  
•VL Open customers can contact their Support Center.  
•Customers who purchased O365 online from Microsoft can submit a request from their Office 365 admin center or contact support."